# Confused about difference between Heroku WEB_CONCURRENCY variable and Celery --concurrency

Tags: heroku, concurrency, celery

I am trying to use Celery to run background tasks in a Heroku Flask application. I'd like to explore configuring things to allow Celery to run more tasks in parallel than the default behavior allows.

My understanding is that the Celery --concurrency option can be used for this by specifying the number of worker processes/threads. But doesn't Heroku's WEB_CONCURRENCY environment variable also specify the same thing, or at least something overlapping/conflicting?

What will happen if I set both WEB_CONCURRENCY and --concurrency? Are they completely separate things, or should I only be using one of them?

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate things and you need to treat them separately.

`WEB_CONCURRENCY` is only a setting [that is set automatically by heroku based on dyno-size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/618), and it's more a recommendation by Heroku how many processes serving web-requests you might want to have on one dyno of a certain size. [Depending on the CPU- and memory-requirements of your servers that can differ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/optimizing-dyno-usage#python).

Which `--concurrency` you choose for celery again depends on your application. While you can start just with `1`, or start with using `WEB_CONCURRENCY` as your worker-concurrency, you definitely have to watch load and memory-usage on these dynos to see if you can increase or have to decrease that number.